# Multiple html classes with c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to add more classes to a table in mvc3 c#.

I now have this:

```
<tr class=@(item.cancelled ? "cancelled" : "")>
```

Is it possible to add an extra class here for example:

```
<tr class= "cancelled added">
```

Comment: MVC and C# have nothing to do with it, it's purely a HTML/CSS related question. AFAIK, you can't have multiple classes on an HTML element.

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Yes you can, i do it all the time. Read the link from Oskar

Comment: @Sam, my mistake... last time I tried it didn't seem to work. CSS isn't really my thing ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <tr class="@(item.cancelled ? "cancelled" : "") added">
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to use it is like this:

```
@using (Html.Td(item, isBlocked))
{
    <div>some contents for the td</div>
}

like this:

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    private class TdElement : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ViewContext _viewContext;
        private bool _disposed;

        public TdElement(ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            if (viewContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("viewContext");
            }
            _viewContext = viewContext;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this._disposed)
            {
                _disposed = true;
                _viewContext.Writer.Write("</td>");
            }
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable Td(this HtmlHelper html, ItemViewModel item, bool isBlocked)
    {
        var td = new TagBuilder("td");
        var title = item.Cancelled 
            ? "Cancelled" 
            : item.Confirmed 
                ? isBlocked 
                    ? "blocked date" 
                    : "" 
                : "Confirm needed";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
        {
            td.Attributes["title"] = title;
        }
        html.ViewContext.Writer.Write(td.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        var element = new TdElement(html.ViewContext);
        return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I prefer Chuck's answer here. It's way shorter and easier to use. But thanks for your work.

Comment: Indeed Chuck's answer works better for you here if you plan on only adding one attribute. it could get long if you need to use a lot of attributes